# ImageView width more than cell width in UITableView Cell - XCode 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode6, iphone-6, iphone-6-plus

I am developing an application in XCode 6 for iOS 8. **I am not using auto-layout.** I am trying to put an ImageView in a UITableView cell. When i run the app on iPhone 6/6 Plus:

1. The size of the imageView becomes double than my cell size if i check all the auto-resizing options.
2. The size of the imageView becomes lesser in width if i uncheck all resizing options except for the left one.

Is this some bug in XCode? Because I think, if i check all the auto-resizing options, and use scale to fill for the imageView, it should scale up and down accordingly, rather than going out of bounds of the view and cell.

All help is appreciated.

Comment: What contentMode are you using for the imageView ? Use the content mode to scale aspect fit.

Comment: With aspect fit, it is still double in height and width, with respect to the cell, if i check all the auto-resizing options. It shrinks to 0 if i uncheck any of the margin auto-resizing options though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding out that it all depends upon the splash screens you have added. AutoResizing proves troublesome on iPhone 6 and 6+ if you have splash screens for them.

But if you remove those splash screens and only keep a splash screen for iPhone 5, then your app will properly scale up and down, hence the bug will be resolved.